# Checking Date format from a string in C#

Tags: c#, string, date, time

I want to check whether a `string` contains dates such as `1/01/2000` and `10/01/2000` in  `dd/MM/yyyy` format.

So far I have tried this.

```
DateTime dDate = DateTime.Parse(inputString);
string.Format("{0:d/MM/yyyy}", dDate);
```

But how can I check if that format is correct to `throw an exception`?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

```
string inputString = "2000-02-02";
DateTime dDate;

if (DateTime.TryParse(inputString, out dDate))
{
    String.Format("{0:d/MM/yyyy}", dDate); 
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("Invalid"); // <-- Control flow goes here
}
```

Answer (score 15):

you can use `DateTime.ParseExact` with the format string

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(inputString, formatString, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Above will throw an exception if the given string not in given format.

use `DateTime.TryParseExact` if you don't need exception in case of format incorrect but you can check the return value of that method to identify whether parsing value success or not.

check [Custom Date and Time Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx)

Comment: But will it also check dates with `single digit` for the `day` for example: `1/01/2000`

Comment: you decide what you need to put as the date time format string, `d` only means no leading zero, `dd` means it will add zero before single day value, if you have multiple valid date time formats you better use one of overload method of `DateTime.ParseExact` which accept multiple datetime formats

Answer (score 6):

I think one of the solutions is to use DateTime.ParseExact or DateTime.TryParseExact

```
DateTime.ParseExact(dateString, format, provider);
```

source: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss.aspx

Comment: this adds a time too. 12am

Answer (score 6):

https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/h9b85w22(v=vs.110).aspx

```
string[] formats= {"M/d/yyyy h:mm:ss tt", "M/d/yyyy h:mm tt", 
                     "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss", "M/d/yyyy h:mm:ss", 
                     "M/d/yyyy hh:mm tt", "M/d/yyyy hh tt", 
                     "M/d/yyyy h:mm", "M/d/yyyy h:mm", 
                     "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm", "M/dd/yyyy hh:mm"};
  string[] dateStrings = {"5/1/2009 6:32 PM", "05/01/2009 6:32:05 PM", 
                          "5/1/2009 6:32:00", "05/01/2009 06:32", 
                          "05/01/2009 06:32:00 PM", "05/01/2009 06:32:00"}; 
  DateTime dateValue;

  foreach (string dateString in dateStrings)
  {
     if (DateTime.TryParseExact(dateString, formats, 
                                new CultureInfo("en-US"), 
                                DateTimeStyles.None, 
                                out dateValue))
        Console.WriteLine("Converted '{0}' to {1}.", dateString, dateValue);
     else
        Console.WriteLine("Unable to convert '{0}' to a date.", dateString);
  }
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use below IsValidDate():

```
 public static bool IsValidDate(string value, string[] dateFormats)
    {
        DateTime tempDate;
        bool validDate = DateTime.TryParseExact(value, dateFormats, DateTimeFormatInfo.InvariantInfo, DateTimeStyles.None, ref tempDate);
        if (validDate)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
```

And you can pass in the value and date formats. For example:

```
var data = "02-08-2019";
var dateFormats = {"dd.MM.yyyy", "dd-MM-yyyy", "dd/MM/yyyy"}

if (IsValidDate(data, dateFormats))
{
    //Do something
}
else
{
    //Do something else
}
```

Comment: to me this looks like a more relevant answer to the OP original question as you get to specify the form in which the date is presented.   I've yet to implement this, but it did stand out that this should in fact be the correct answer.

Comment: you will definitely get an error on following line : var dateFormats = {"dd.MM.yyyy", "dd-MM-yyyy", "dd/MM/yyyy"}

Answer (score 3):

you could always try:

```
Regex r = new Regex(@"\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4}");

r.isMatch(inputString);
```

this will check that the string is in the format "02/02/2002"
you may need a bit more if you want to ensure that it is a valid date like dd/mm/yyyy

Comment: Please provide explanation while you answer

Answer (score 2):

Use an array of valid dates format, check [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h9b85w22(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
string[] formats = { "d/MM/yyyy", "dd/MM/yyyy" };
DateTime parsedDate;
var isValidFormat= DateTime.TryParseExact(inputString, formats, new CultureInfo("en-US"), DateTimeStyles.None, out parsedDate);

if(isValidFormat)
{
    string.Format("{0:d/MM/yyyy}", parsedDate);
}
else
{
    // maybe throw an Exception
}
```

Comment: This is a very good approach in situations that we are unsure of the date formats. Like instances where Azure act differently in many platforms

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
DateTime dDate;
dDate = DateTime.TryParse(inputString);
String.Format("{0:d/MM/yyyy}", dDate);
```

see this link for more info. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ch92fbc1.aspx

Comment: DateTime.TryParse doesn't have an overload that takes two parameters as an argument